# Updating Table After Left Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

Simple reprex below:

```
drop table if exists my_table;

create table my_table
(
    ref int,
    customer_name char(50)
);

insert into my_table(ref, customer_name)
values      (1001, 'Alan'), 
            (1002, 'Bob'),
            (1003, 'Christine'),
            (1004, 'David'),
            (1005, 'Elizabeth');

drop table if exists lookups;

create table lookups
(
    ref int,
    gender char(6)
);

insert into lookups(ref, gender)
values            (1001, 'male'),
                  (1002, 'male'),
                  (1004, 'male'),
                  (1005, 'female');
```

I'd like to update `my_table` to include `gender`, the values for which should be retrieved using a `left join` on the `lookups` table. I don't know how to do this.

Is it a two stage process ie do I need to first insert a `gender` column into `my_table` and then perform an `update ... left join ...` query?

Comment: That isn't how you update a table.  You are trying to create a new table and there is already one existing called my_table.  You need to lookup the UPDATE command.

Comment: In your query `into      new_table` that new_table does not exist to insert into whereas the other one DOES and thus selecting from/into the same table is NOT an update.

Comment: The `SELECT <COLUMNS> INTO Table` is not an update statement. What are you trying to do, create a new table i.e new_table and also have the data updated in the existing table ?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss The INTO command will create a new table if one does not already exist, so the INTO new_table will create new_table.  To recreate new_table later on, it would need to be dropped first.

Comment: @DataWrangler Thanks. I'd ideally like to update `my_table` (and not create `new_table` at all). Do I need to do something with the `update` command and not use the `into` stuff? Do I need to manually add a `gender` column to `my_table` first before using an `update` command?

Comment: @Mike Yes, I knew that part my comment was somewhat cryptic there on that IMHO bad practice and the other differs.

Comment: @Alan ref https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @Alan Can you update your question with what it is you want to update please.  An UPDATE can only update existing values within the table.  If you are trying to "Add" the gender to my_table then that won't work.

Comment: @Mike thanks - have reworded slightly now

Comment: @Alan You'd need to add the column gender to my_table, you can then update this column with the values from lookups using a left join in the UPDATE sub-query.  Take a look at the link Mark has posted above.  If I get chance I will post a proper answer later tonight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two step process. First, you need to add the `gender` column to `my_table`. Make sure it's nullable, because otherwise you'd have to declare it with a default, and assigning people a default gender seems... problematic.

Then just update `my_table` by joining to `lookups`. Inner join is fine here; you CAN do left join as well, but if you re-run this and use a left join, you risk updating any existing `gender` values with `NULL` where they don't exist in `lookups`

```
-- Create the column if it doesn't exist
if not exists 
(
    select 1
    from sys.columns
    where object_id = object_id('my_table')
        and name = 'gender'
)
begin
    alter table my_table
        add gender varchar(10) null
end
-- You need to do this in a separate batch or it won't know that 
-- the column was created and you'll get errors 
go
-- Update the genders.
update t
set gender = s.gender
from my_table t
inner join lookups s
    on t.ref = s.ref
-- not REALLY necessary, but in case you re-run this after the fact and something has changed
-- This will prevent that from getting wiped out
where t.gender is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering this as an exercise in how:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #my_table;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #lookups;

CREATE TABLE #my_table (ref INT, customer_name VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO #my_table (ref, customer_name) VALUES
(1001, 'Alan'),  (1002, 'Bob'), (1003, 'Christine'), (1004, 'David'), (1005, 'Elizabeth');

CREATE TABLE #lookups (ref INT, gender CHAR(6));
INSERT INTO #lookups (ref, gender) VALUES
(1001, 'male'), (1002, 'male'), (1004, 'male'), (1005, 'female');

ALTER TABLE #my_table ADD gender CHAR(6);

UPDATE m
   SET gender = l.gender
  FROM #my_table m
    INNER JOIN #lookups l
      ON m.ref = l.ref;

SELECT *
  FROM #my_table;
```

| ref | customer_name | gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Alan | male |
| 1002 | Bob | male |
| 1003 | Christine |  |
| 1004 | David | male |
| 1005 | Elizabeth | female |

First we drop the temp tables, if they exist. Then we create and populate them.

Since you want to add a column we need to then execute an `ALTER` on the table to add the column, with it's data type.

Then we can execute an `UPDATE` to populate the values from the lookup table.

You should spend some time familiarizing yourself with the various data types, and the pros and cons of them. In this instance we probably wouldn't want to use `VARCHAR` for a name, as there are many characters which could be present in the name which are not supported by `VARCHAR`, `NVARCHAR` does include these.

You may want to spend some time looking at how relationships are typically fleshed out. A table called 'Genders' might be better used here, having a relationship to a table called 'Customers' with a column of 'GenderID':

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Customers;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Genders;

CREATE TABLE #Customers (CustomerID INT, CustomerName NVARCHAR(50), GenderID TINYINT);
INSERT INTO #Customers (CustomerID, CustomerName, GenderID) VALUES
(1001, 'Alan', 1),  (1002, 'Bob', 1), (1003, 'Christine', 2), (1004, 'David', 4), (1005, 'Elizabeth', 2);

CREATE TABLE #Genders (GenderID TINYINT IDENTITY, GenderName VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO #Genders (GenderName) VALUES
('Male'),  ('Female'), ('Other'), ('Nonbinary');
```

This would allow you to maintain the genders of all customers by updating them in the lookup table, rather than having to update all the rows in 'Customers'.